# VBA : datepart function

Tags: excel, vba

In my where close I have:

```
datepart(pr.DT_DEB)>'" & Ma_date & "'
```

I use the `Datepart` function because my `pr.DT_DEB` is like `01JAN2018:00:00:00` and `'" & Ma_date & "'` is like `25/11/2020`.

Do I need to modify `01JAN2018:00:00:00`  to `01/01/2018` for my where close ? I suppose that `datepart` function is not right. Do you know please the function for modifying the data ?

Thank you !

Comment: [`DatePart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datepart-function) requires twoinputs.  Also you will need to parse the date to make it something that VBA can convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Format`:

```vb
? CDate(Format(Left(pr.DT_DEB, 9), "@@ @@@ @@@@")) > Ma_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function

```vb
Function ToDate(s) As Date
   
   s = Mid(s, 1, 2) & "-" & Mid(s, 3, 3) & "-" & Mid(s, 6, 4)
   ToDate = DateValue(s)

End Function

Sub test()

   Dim Ma_date As Date
   Ma_date = "25/11/2020"
   Debug.Print ToDate("01JAN2018:00:00:00") > Ma_date
   Debug.Print ToDate("26NOV2020:00:00:00") > Ma_date

End Sub
```